# Values of MySQL table not readable for Console

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I´m not sure if something like this has already been asked, but I didn´t find anything which helped me yet. I am storing data in a MySQL Table, one of the colums stores E-Mails. The thing is the E-Mail Adresses are shown in PHPMyAdmin but if I call

```
    SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `email` = 'me@example.com'
```

or

```
    SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `email`
```

MySQL returns an empty result, although both Querys should return minimum 1 result. `email` is not the PRIMARY_KEY in the table.

Does anyone have a clue what´s the Problem?

Thanks

EDIT: The query does work for the other colums of the table but not for this one

EDIT 2: The colum is labeld newsmail, has type Text with undefined Length (I also tried VARCHAR with length 255 which didn´t solve the problem), has no Null-Value and isn´t nullable, the charset is UTF-8_general_ci , no attributes, and the following fields are all blank

Comment: Where are executing those queries?

Comment: Wrong database.

Comment: could you show us an example of emails stored in your Database !!

Comment: @delephin in PDO and PHP MyAdmin console. Both don´t work.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thats not the problem it works for the other colums

Comment: @PacMan Because of privacy protection I can´t show you a actual screenshot but I`ll add the configuration of the Colum in the question

Comment: `SELECT * FROM \`table\`` works?

Comment: Try `latin1_general_ci` - just to see if something changes.

Comment: no it didn´t. I just wrote a script to see if I start a requery in PDO and readout the table it can still read the email colum which was the case. So I created a new colum and transferred all the emails to it with the PDO query but that didn´t change anything either

Comment: set my E-Mail in the database into a different colum which is not set for the other users yet. Suddenly MySQL is able to find it. Only difference is that this colum was nullable. set email colum nullable eiter but still couldn´t found it there

Comment: Now I copied the whole colum to the one which found the entry but for some kind of reason it didn´t work anymore. I removed all except one and the query could find it again. Is it possible that the Query doesnt search throught all ~170 entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the problem. There was nothing wrong with the MySQL itself, but the problem was, that the email was the last element in every line of the file that I imported it from. So the email wasn´t 'mail@example.com' but instead 'mail@example.com\n' but the \n was of course not displayed by PHPMyAdmin. This explains why the query didn´t found it. And always when I put a single entry in a different colum I typed it by hand while the \n was copied when copieing the whole table with PHP.
Thanks to everyone who tried helping anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly do you execute those queries? In the phpMyAdmin SQL query console or on a linux console?

If you are on a linux console and issue the mysql command be sure to add the **;** at the end of each command:

```
# mysql
mysql> use database;
mysql> select * from table where 1;
```

It should return you all the entries from that specific table from the selected database

Comment: I want to use it in PHP - PDO but as the query there didn´t work I tried in the PHP MyAdmin Console. The query works for the other colums of the table but not for this one.